# A technician injected malware into my computer without my knowledge

Tags: virus

So this fixer that I asked to fix my busted front audio ports injected my PC with KMS-R@in in order to get rid of the activate windows watermark without my consent/knowledge, and it gave me Floxif.E and Floxif.H, and updated the drivers to fix the back ports, which wasn't even what I asked him for, is there any legal action I can do to make him take responsibility?

By the way, his store's affiliated with/backed by ASUS.

Comment: *"... is there any legal action I can do to make him take responsibility"* - this is off-topic here. Try [law.se] instead.